# Align to the right second and following lines of a group of long equations

Tags: math-mode, mathtools, multline

following the chat messages of yesterday I open a question on the main site.

So I need to write long equations, and for readability I prefer to use `multline` and `multlined` over `align`. The equations are of the form

```
function = VeryLongExpression1+AnotherVeryLongExpression2+...
```

I would like to indent it in the following way

```
function = VeryLongExpression1
                      +AnotherVeryLongExpression2
                 +StillAnotherVeryLongExpression3
                                             +...
```

All lines, except the first one of course, should be aligned to the right, not overlapping with the equation number (which I don't use anyway).

At the moment I'm using the `multlined` environment as

```
\begin{equation*}
function=
\begin{multlined}[t]
\shoveright{VeryLongExpression1}\\
\shoveright{+AnotherVeryLongExpression2}\\
\shoveright{+StillAnotherVeryLongExpression3}\\
\shoveright{+...}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation*}
```

but `\shoveright` does not work on the last line, as reported also on the doc of `mathtools`.

Is there any way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of `multline*` and `aligned` seems to do the job.

[image]

No need for `\shoveleft` or `\shoveright` directives.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline*' and 'aligned' environments

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\text{function} =\text{AVeryVeryVeryLongExpression1}\\
\begin{aligned}
{}+\text{AnotherVeryVeryVeryLongExpression2}      \\
{}+\text{StillAnotherVeryVeryVeryLongExpression3} \\
{}+\dotsb
\end{aligned}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comments and claims: I'm afraid I am *unable to replicate the issue* the OP says they are experiencing if the `flowfram` package is loaded and a `multline*` environment is employed. As the following screenshot shows, the framelines do *not* encroach on the sample text above the `multline*` environment. I can only guess that the OP's issue is caused by some coding choices which haven't been revealed so far and which I am unable to divine on my own -- possibly because my divination skills are simply worthless.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline*' and 'aligned' environments
\usepackage{lipsum}  % <-- new
\usepackage[draft]{flowfram} % <-- new
\begin{document}
\noindent
\lipsum[1][1-3] % generate two lines of filler text
\begin{multline*}
\text{function} =\text{AVeryVeryVeryLongExpression1}\\
\begin{aligned}
{}+\text{AnotherVeryVeryVeryLongExpression2}      \\
{}+\text{StillAnotherVeryVeryVeryLongExpression3} \\
{}+\dotsb
\end{aligned}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this works very well, but the environment multline causes overlflow(content exits its frame box, see pics https://imgur.com/a/nD8QhBb), while multlined inside equation do not

Comment: @john - I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. The image in the link you provided does not appear to substantiate your claim, and neither does the image I posted above. I can only assume that the issue you've encountered is related to information not contained in your posting, such as the fact that your actual equations could be longer than the string `StillAnotherVeryVeryVeryLongExpression3`. Unfortunately, my divination and mind-reading skills are pretty much worthless. If you want me to provide usable advice on a real issue, it would help if you provided more relevant information.

Comment: You're right, my english is not very good, I'll try to be more clear. I'm compiling in draft mode, using a package that draw boxes around frames (the name of the package is 'flowframe' using the 'draft' option), which are the light grey lines you see. Here you can see better https://imgur.com/a/jhJ0Ocd . As you can see, the text above the equation exit the boxes. This happen with 'multline', while when I use 'multlined' inside 'equation' this do not happen.

Comment: @john - Please see the addendum I posted. I am simply unable to replicate the issue you say you're encountering. I am pretty confident in my view, though, that using a `multline*` environment does *not* cause the running text to overflow the edges of the text block.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your addendum. The issue is still not resolved, but, as you said, I guess at this point it has to do with the fact that I'm not using a default class, but rather a custom template with narrow margins. I'll try to look into that. Thanks again. Can I ask you why the '{}' at the start of each line are needed?

Comment: So apparently the problem was the package 'flowfram'. I don't know why, but when used together with 'multline' it shift to the left the content, out of the frame. I'm using another package to display the boxes of the frame and now works.

Comment: @john -- the `{}` particles ahead of the three `+` symbols serve to inform TeX to treat the `+` symbols as binary rather than as unary operators. (Remove the `{}` elements and note that the whitespace between `+` and the subsequent material is gone.)

Comment: Thank you again!